# How to replace data in a certain range with a variable?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm new to machine learning,

I have a dataset :

[image]

I want to create a "bucket" :

> [0-25] = A
>
> [26-50] = B
>
> [51-75] = C
>
> [76-100] = D

I tried `panda.cut()` :

```
bins = [-1, 26, 51, 76, 100]    
labels = ["A", "B", "C", "D"]    
dataset['UAS'] = pd.cut(dataset['UAS'], bins=bins, labels=labels)
```

Result :

[image]

It only works on a 1-dimensional array.
Any tips/lib to "cut" all columns simultaneously without repeating the code?

Thanks a lot.

** tried `apply()` :

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
#only numeric columns
cols = dataset.select_dtypes(np.number).columns
#pass cut for columns from list
dataset[cols] = dataset[cols].apply(lambda x: pd.cut(x, bins=bins, labels=labels))
```

Comment: code return an error, '<' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str'

Comment: @RomarioRio - can you test now?

Comment: It works. I guess some of the data isn't an integer. Thanks a lot.